# Restriction for AWS WAF configuration country list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf, web-application-firewall

I set a WAF rule to limit the country list to allow traffic and block the requests for other countries not on the list.

I can provide a maximum of 50 countries listed in the rule. I am getting a validation error if the list exceeds 50.

Can we provide a country list of more than 50?